# Is there a way to cache all fetch requests on a site?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a environment which is very unstable and therefore i would like to know if there is a way to cache the entire site requests at a given time.

My expected scenario would be:

1. Turn on the caching mechanism (either a Chrome extension or a local script)
2. Navigate on the site's pages which I'm interested in caching with the caching mechanism turned on (ex: /home & /dashboard)
3. For these 2 pages save all requests responses made locally (XHR, media, etc)
4. Wait long enough in order for this page to have other data in it.
5. Enter the selected pages from 2. and have all the requests loaded from the state it was when caching mechanism was turned on at 2.

Basically, i would like to save the pages data state and have all the requests redirected to my local cache in order to be able to get back in time when i had the data i want.